# Chrome FullScreenActivity quits with StrictMode violation

Tags: android, google-chrome

I am running a Web App as a Full Screen Activity in Google Chrome for Android. This works quite well, but at some point in time Chrome quits and Logcat tells me that Google Chrome has violated the StrictMode policy. This app runs on one machine in Kiosk mode (iDisplay tablet from Outform with Android 4.4.2) and should run 24/7.

The logcat output is as follows:

```
05-20 06:37:52.002   429   709 I ActivityManager: Process com.android.chrome:sandboxed_process0 (pid 1592) has died.
05-20 06:37:52.042   888   888 W ScreenOrientationListener: Removing an inexistent observer!
05-20 06:06:21.082  1358  1358 D StrictMode: StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=205 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskReadViolation: policy=31 violation=2
05-20 06:06:21.082  1358  1358 D StrictMode:    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onReadFromDisk(StrictMode.java:1135)
05-20 06:06:21.082  1358  1358 D StrictMode:    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:106)
05-20 06:06:21.082  1358  1358 D StrictMode:    at libcore.io.IoUtils.canOpenReadOnly(IoUtils.java:163)
05-20 06:06:21.082  1358  1358 D StrictMode:    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findLibrary(DexPathList.java:384)
05-20 06:06:21.082  1358  1358 D StrictMode:    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findLibrary(BaseDexClassLoader.java:77)
05-20 06:06:21.082  1358  1358 D StrictMode:    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:356)
05-20 06:06:21.082  1358  1358 D StrictMode:    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
05-20 06:06:21.082  1358  1358 D StrictMode:    at com.google.android.libraries.social.jni.crashreporter.NativeCrashHandler.a(PG:189)
05-20 06:06:21.082  1358  1358 D StrictMode:    at com.google.android.libraries.social.jni.crashreporter.NativeCrashHandler.a(PG:87)
05-20 06:06:21.082  1358  1358 D StrictMode:    at com.google.android.apps.gmm.base.app.d.<init>(PG:524)
05-20 06:06:21.082  1358  1358 D StrictMode:    at com.google.android.apps.gmm.base.app.GoogleMapsApplication.b(PG:166)
05-20 06:06:21.082  1358  1358 D StrictMode:    at com.google.android.apps.gmm.base.app.GoogleMapsApplication.onCreate(PG:111)
05-20 06:06:21.082  1358  1358 D StrictMode:    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
05-20 06:06:21.082  1358  1358 D StrictMode:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4344)
05-20 06:06:21.082  1358  1358 D StrictMode:    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-20 06:06:21.082  1358  1358 D StrictMode:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
05-20 06:06:21.082  1358  1358 D StrictMode:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-20 06:06:21.082  1358  1358 D StrictMode:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-20 06:06:21.082  1358  1358 D StrictMode:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-20 06:06:21.082  1358  1358 D StrictMode:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-20 06:06:21.082  1358  1358 D StrictMode:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-20 06:06:21.082  1358  1358 D StrictMode:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
05-20 06:06:21.082  1358  1358 D StrictMode:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
05-20 06:06:21.082  1358  1358 D StrictMode:    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This message appears several times and then the window is gone.

After the last ModeViolationException the message

```
05-20 06:37:52.052   888   888 W ChildProcessConnection: onServiceDisconnected (crash or killed by oom): pid=1592
```

tells me that Chrome has died.

The questions are: Can i do something about it? Is there a Chrome-Version without Strict Mode (i don't think so but at least i could ask)? Is there any other possibility to show a Web App in Fullscreen Mode? Can i disable maybe the Strict Mode in Android itself?
My first guess for a solution would be a Watchdog app to observe if Google Chrome has crashed and then relaunch it. I am open for any other - better - solutions.

Thanks four your help,
Lukas

Comment: "Can i do something about it?" -- file a bug report, with steps to reproduce the crash. "Can i disable maybe the Strict Mode in Android itself?" -- no, because it is in the app. "Is there any other possibility to show a Web App in Fullscreen Mode?" -- there are many Web browsers available for Android, and you can always use `WebView` in your own Android app.

Comment: The error happens not everytime at the same time, so it is very hard to reproduce. I assume it is an intended behaviour for the android system, but it is a destructive behaviour for the kiosk installation environment. This error appeared two times over the last five weeks, but it happens - and can happen, when a customer wants to use the screen. I have tried a WebView but the app crashes nearly immediately.

Comment: "I assume it is an intended behaviour for the android system" -- not a crash, no.

Comment: I've found a solution: I have disabled the developer options and chromes crashed not any more since then.